# Why does LD_LIBRARY_PATH only works in ~/Desktop/?

Tags: bash, nautilus

If I run application **app** from `~/Desktop/` I am getting:

```
/home/me/Desktop/app: error while loading shared libraries: somelib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I have created this script called **app.sh**:

```
DIR="$(dirname "$0")"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR
$DIR/app
```

And then **app** runs.

However, I decided that I don't want to have it on the Desktop, but to have under `~/dev/apps/`. So I move all files (app, somelib.so.0, app.sh) and get this error when I run the script:

```
/home/me/dev/apps/app: error while loading shared libraries: somelib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I move it to `~/foo/bar/` still doesn't run.

Please note:

- All directories and files have the same permissions.
- All files are in the same directory.
- I call the script from `~/Destop/app.sh` or `~/dev/app/app.sh`.
- I am running it from `/home/me`

Is this a normal behavior or is there something wrong with my setup or configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that when copying all the files in Nautilus, the dynamic library was being copied as a soft link and the file size was much smaller.

Deleting library it and copying it again from bash fixed the problem.

I am adding Nautilus as a tag to the question.
However I cannot reproduce this issue anymore, even when copy-pasting again from Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

You can add explicit path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/me/Desktop/app/lib
```

(use example path to the library)

Also you can add this in your `.bash_profile`

Also you can create softlink in `/usr/lib` to your library